# How to get derivative of f(x) = x(4-x) without canceling out all useful terms?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I need to plug the following function into the first principles derivative function:

f(x) = x(4-x)

I've done this about 6 or 7 times now (and my desk is a mountain of torn up paper), I've watched and rewatched my lectures. How to I plug this into the derivative f`(x) = f(x + delta x) - f(x)/delta x without canceling out the useful terms?

I always seem to end up with zero before I can solve it.

I've been doing it this way:

```
f`(x) = (x(4-x)) + delta x - x(4-x)/delta x
      = 4x - x^2 + delta x - 4x + x^2/delta x
      = 4x - x^2 - 4x + x^2
```

And as you can see, at this point all the terms cancel themselves out. I'm really lost.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The way you 'plug' $\Delta x$ is wrong, try to recheck that.

Comment: How so? I've been tearing my hair out over this for hours so I can't really see the forest for the trees right now.

Comment: $f(x+\Delta x)=(x+\Delta x)(4-(x+\Delta x))$. Also, you're forgetting your $\lim$'s.

Comment: See....doing this at 1am is bad, now I get it...

Comment: No problem, please edit your post adding further attempts when you try this again.

Answer (score 2):

You start with $f(x) = x(4-x).$

The derivative is

$$f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x},$$

assuming the limit exists.

To calculate the $f(x + \Delta x)$ part, you substitute $x + \Delta x$ everywhere you see $x$ in $x(4-x)$.

Some perhaps clearer examples:

$$f(7a) = 7a(4-7a)$$

$$f(2 \pi e^3) = 2 \pi e^3 (4 - 2 \pi e^3).$$

Then,

$$f(x + \Delta x) = (x + \Delta x)(4 - x - \Delta x) = 4x - x^2 - x \Delta x + 4 \Delta x - x \Delta x - (\Delta x)^2.$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = x (4-x) = 4x - x^2$

$f(x + \Delta x) = 4 (x + \Delta x) - (x + \Delta x)^2 = \ldots$